# CSS Animation Forward then Backward Flickering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS animation that when a user clicks an element it animates to the right then when they click it again it animates to the left.  The problem I have is that it is introducing flickering.  I know the reason, but I'm not sure the best way to fix it.  I want the most elegant solution for this problem.

I setup a jsFiddle (WebKit only) here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ad5c/2/

The CSS:

```
.animateRight{
    -webkit-animation: goRightLeft 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animateLeft{
    -webkit-animation: goRightLeft 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;    
}
@-webkit-keyframes goRightLeft {
    0%{margin-left: 0px;}
    100%{margin-left: 100px;}
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
this.animateBox = function(className){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
    box.className = "box";
    setTimeout(function(){
        box.className = "box " + className;
    },1);
};
```

When you click the Animate Right it works as expected, but when you click the Animate Left it will flicker to the left and then animate as expected.  The reason is that you have to remove the class and add another in order to get the animate to run again, but I don't know the best way to get this working.  I figure I could add a class when removing the previous animation that has it in its current state, but that seems wrong to me.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

***Reason for flickering:***

You are applying class `box` on click before setting the next animationClass which makes the box go to left abruptly. and then you are applying the animation to go reverse. So it causes flickering while it abrupty goes left (removal of class) and adding class in timeout causes revereses animation according to the fillmode and direction in `animateLeft` class and makes it even more worser as `goRightLeft` again adds margin pulls it to right due to the margin in the rule and  `webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;` pushes to to the left. So one approach i mentioned here is to do the reverse (adding/reducing) the margin.

Here is one solution for this:

For real reverse animation you need to apply margin decresing from 100px to 0 as you  do while forward animation. So just add `keyframes` for `LeftToRight` and apply that in animation.

#### Css

```
.animateRight{
    -webkit-animation: goRightLeft 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.animateLeft{
    -webkit-animation: goLeftRight 1s; /* Note the goLeftRight animation */
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;


}
@-webkit-keyframes goRightLeft {
    0%{margin-left: 0px;}
    100%{margin-left: 100px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes goLeftRight { /* Note the new keyframes rule for reverse animation*/
    0%{margin-left: 100px;}
    100%{margin-left: 0px;}
}
```

#### Script

```
this.animateBox = function(className){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
    box.className = "box " + className;

};
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WkU8B/)

Comment: Well, that does work.  I had been using add/removeClass in jQuery which is why i had the setTimeout and removing first.  I just hooked it up like that for the demo.  I am fine with not using jQuery for this, so this is a good solution for me.  I would be interested in how to best do it in jQuery though (without .animate). Thanks!

Comment: @Matt do you mean with out using specific css rules as you are doing now and jquery animate method?